# How to make a plane responsive to light?

Tags: lighting

I need the plane color to be white and the lambs to only expose the plane beneath it. However the plane just lights up on it's own even when using really dark colors. How do I fix this? I've checked the world lighting. Emissions, and none of these are even on. I'm on cycles engine.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're going for, but I made this scene with just text, a plane, and a single spotlight (Material added to the text - everything else default). This is in cycles engine, and I left my world properties panel open so you can see the settings. If you cannot reproduce, you may be suffering from some kind of bug, but I think more likely you have too strong a world background (cycles picks up even faint World Lighting), or hidden lights. Look at the example and let me know what I'm missing:

[image: Test]